# Image data in JS

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to know if I've understood this correctly.

I loop my map and load sprites on the map.

So I decided to store the pixel information in an array so that when I click with my mouse I check if its in a pixel array range and get the id related to it (effectively being pixel accurate for detecting what object was clicked?)

This is my thinking process:

I draw the sprite:

```
ctx.drawImage(castle[id], abposx, abposy - (imgheight/2));  
myImageData[sdata[i][j][1]] = 
      ctx.getImageData(abposx, abposy, castle[id].width, castle[id].height);
```

Then some how with left click, check if mouse `x` and mouse `y` is `inbetween` the range of the arrays and return the value of `myImageData`?

Or have I misunderstood what `getImageData` is about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getImageData` gives you all of the pixel data for an image. Basically you only need to use `getImageData` if you are doing any sort of pixel manipulation with the image, like changing its hue/color, or applying a filter, or need specific data, such as the r/g/b, or alpha values. In order to check for pixel perfect collisions you an do something like the following:

```
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
    if(imageData.data[3] !== 0){
        // you have a collision!
    }
```

`imageData.data[0-3]` holds an array of data, 0-2 are the color values r/g/b, and 3 is the alpha value. So we assume if the alpha is 0, it must be a transparent portion. Also note, in the example and fiddle I am grabbing the data from the canvas itself, so if there was an image behind it that wasnt transparent it would count as not being transparent. The best way to do it if you have many images that overlap is to keep a copy of the image by itself offscreen somewhere and do a translation of the coordinates to get the position on the image. Heres a good [MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas) explaining `getImageData` as well.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/wb7dk/)**

Comment: Not quite as i only want selection to be on non alpha pixels =/

Comment: Well in that case then yes, you would want to use `getImageData` should of specified that in the original question :P

Comment: @Dave http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/wb7dk/ here you go, will go ahead and update my answer as well.

Comment: That makes perfect sense but one slight question...if there was a background image...(lets say a grass terrain).. would it see alpha when over the sprite image(if its drawn after the background images) or will it detect the pixels behind the alpha?

Comment: @Dave: If `ctx` is the context for a canvas which contains only the sprite, it should work as desired. If `ctx` contains the entire visible area (with background images and such), then it will detect the opaqueness in the background, which is probably undesired.

Comment: @Dave: Just have a canvas that isn't part of the document. Before testing, clear the canvas and then draw just the sprite you want to test. Then test it in the usual way.

Comment: Yeh but in order for sprites on a map im guna have to use two canvas' or can i do:
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");  
canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas"); 
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");

Two vars to same canvas ? =/

Comment: @icktoofay is correct, just use in memory canvases to test, thats what I meant in the last part of my answer. The in memory canvas  just has the image on it, and you do a coord translation so like on the world its x : 200, y :300 ,and on the image its 10, 10, so youd test the temp canvas at 10x10 see if the transparent or not. If I get time today I could make a demo showing that as well.